# Power BI Combining Columns and use lookup

Tags: powerbi, lookup

I have two reports: first report has a column with sponsor names (name: Sponsor) and the other report also has sponsor names but written differently (name: Companies). Example:

```
**Sponsor**    
Apple       
Target      
Amazon      
IBM         
Samsung
```

```
**Sponsor (Other)**  
Apple Inc  
Target LLC  
Amazon Marketplace  
IBM Computers  
Samsung Company
```

I have appended these two columns so that they are in the same report called Sponsor_All, column names the same as above.  What I would like is to create a new column where it would pull in the names from the sponsor column and change the name of the Sponsor (Other) column based on a lookup table so that all of the names are labeled like the sponsor column. Hope thats makes sense.

Comment: What is the logic for matching records between those 2 columns? Values are not same, how you wants to apply the LOOKUP logic?

Comment: I need to show expenses by sponsor but one report displays sponsors in a different way so I need to make them similar and combine them to do that.

Comment: Then just apply some transformation on column you wants to change value in. Define the logic like - replace specific part or value or keep/remove specific length. Your data so you have better insight to transform data :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is conditional column of some sort.

First thing I would recommend, when you append the two tables, if column names are the same it will append values from both tables into one column, instead of having two columns with different name and a bunch of null values. After that you can either add Conditional Column and hard code the values (so it will be something like: if Sponsor starts with 'Apple' then 'Apple' etc.).

This is not the best approach though, cause you will have to maintain these conditions manually. Better if there's some sort of pattern that you can notice, e.g. in your example I see that to get from Sponsor (other) to Sponsor you just need to extract the first word. If this is the pattern you always have you can use Custom Column and use formula to extract only the first word.[image: custom and conditional columns]

Lastly, if you already have some sort of lookup table you can merge it (after appending together Sponsors and Sponsors(Other) into one column) and use fuzzy lookup option. In all honesty though I never used it and not sure how good it is. If it gives you good enough result you can "clean it up" in next step with custom or conditional column.
[image]